# How to efficiently eliminate data from select when rows are different by one column value

Tags: mysql, join, select

I have such TABLE with data:

```
A  | B  | C  |  D | E 
-----------------------
a1 | b1 | c1 | d1 | PA
a1 | b1 | c1 | d1 | PR
a2 | b2 | c2 | d2 | PA
a3 | b3 | c3 | d3 | PA
a3 | b3 | c3 | d3 | PR
```

- row1 has its counterpart row2 (they are only different by col E)
- row3 has no counterpart - unique
- row4 has its counterpart row5  ( same as first statement - col E )

the query should gave me a result like this:

```
A  | B  | C  |  D | E 
-----------------------
a2 | b2 | c2 | d2 | PA
```

only unique row which has no counterpart -
**no row with same set of data only which different only by value in column E**

- we can apply here a few approaches which one will be most effective if we have more rows with its counterparts as unique rows (without counterpart)
- which join use ?
- which one created select statement subtract or add ?

**ps.** an extended case

```
A  | B    | C  |  D                  | E 
----------------------------------------
a1 | b1   | c1 | 2017-05-16 11:46:36 | PA
a1 | b1   | c1 | 2017-05-16 11:46:37 | PR
a2 | b2   | c2 | 2017-05-17 01:34:28 | PA
a3 | null | c3 | 2017-05-12 19:14:15 | PA    
a3 | b3   | c3 | 2017-05-12 19:14:15 | PR   
a4 | b4   | c4 | 2017-05-12 19:16:15 | PA  
a4 | b4   | c4 | 2017-05-12 23:16:15 | PR
```

- column A -D may contain null values  (row4)
- column D is a TIMESTAMP  and it could vary from its counterpart by 1-2minutes   (row1, row2)
- we add the max difference in timestamp  = example 2 minutes (row6 has no counterpart as row7 vs row6 timestamp difference is greeter than 2 minuts (4 hours)
- we don't want any row with PR in our result

expected result:

```
A  | B    | C  |  D                  | E 
----------------------------------------
a2 | b2   | c2 | 2017-05-17 01:34:28 | PA
a4 | b4   | c4 | 2017-05-12 19:16:15 | PA
```

Comment: In your extended case, which is the intended result? Rows 4 and 5 where considered "equivalent, and non-reported" in your original scenario. What should happen now?  Which time-threshold to use to consider that two times are equivalent or not?

Comment: @joanolo see edit

Comment: See edit on response.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use a `JOIN`. If you would like to look for rows that have a set of columns in common (in your case, all but one), I would just `GROUP` the rows by the common columns. Then, restrict which groups you want to return (using a `HAVING` clause):

```
SELECT
    A, B, C, D, min(E) AS E
FROM
    t
GROUP BY
    A, B, C, D
HAVING
    count(*) = 1 ;
```

The `min(E)` part is just a trick to be "SQL compliant". `max(E)`, or `first(E)` (for the databases that have it) would do the job as well. As you're choosing just groups with a single row, the `min` value of a column within the group is the *single* value there is. In mySQL 5.6 and earlier, leaving `E` as a column would work as well; although this is not SQL standard and doesn't work in 5.7 (thanks to 
[ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9) for pointing the fact that this doesn't work on 5.7).

**[Results are](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf303c/1/0)**:

```
|  A |  B |  C |  D |  E |
|----|----|----|----|----|
| a2 | b2 | c2 | d2 | PA |
```

[You can get everything at this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf303c/1)

---

You can also take a different approach. Look for rows that literally comply with what you're looking for: that is, it does NOT exist another row with the same `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` and different `E`. In this case, use an `EXISTS` condition in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    A, B, C, D, E
FROM
    t AS t0
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 
         *
    FROM
        t AS t1
    WHERE
             t1.A  = t0.A
         AND t1.B  = t0.B
         AND t1.C  = t0.C
         AND t1.D  = t0.D
         AND t1.E <> t0.E
    ) ;
```

Older versions of MySQL would probably not handle this query too well, because `EXISTS` conditions are not well optimized. mySQL 5.7 does a decent job; and so do most other databases (Oracle, MS SQL Server, PostgreSQL, ...) . You do need an index on `(A, B, C, D, E)` (or, at least, `(A, B, C, D)` to be really performant.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf303c/3)

---

The two queries will not work the same in the case where you have two exact duplicate rows (which I interpret is a case not allowed by your spec). [The first one will return *no* rows](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15d1f4/1/0), whereas [the second one will return *both* rows](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15d1f4/1/1).

---

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
    `A` varchar(2), 
    `B` varchar(2), 
    `C` varchar(2), 
    `D` varchar(2), 
    `E` varchar(2)
) ;

INSERT INTO t
    (`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`)
VALUES
    ('a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'PA'),
    ('a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'PR'),
    ('a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'PA'),
    ('a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3', 'PA'),
    ('a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3', 'PR');
```

---

For your **extended case**, the second query is your starting point.

Change your equalities with whichever conditions meet your needs.

For instance, if your `D` columns is a timestamp, and you want to consider that "two times are equivalent if the difference is less than 2 minutes"... then change

```
t1.D = t0.D
```

by

```
abs( unix_timestamp(t1.D) - unix_timestamp(t0.D) ) < 120 -- seconds
```

The possibility of nulls (that work as "jokers") should be handled with:

```
(t1.A = t0.A or t0.A is null or t1.A is null)
```

If E is nullable, then the comparison is done with

```
NOT (t1.E <=> t0.E)
```

which is mySQL equivalent of `(t1.E is distinct from t0.E)`

This will give you:

```
 SELECT
     A, B, C, D, E
 FROM
     t AS t0
 WHERE
     NOT EXISTS 
     (SELECT 
          *
     FROM
         t AS t1
     WHERE
              (t1.A = t0.A or t1.A is NULL or t0.A is NULL)
          AND (t1.B = t0.B or t1.B is NULL or t0.B is NULL)
          AND (t1.C = t0.C or t1.C is NULL or t0.C is NULL)
          AND (abs( unix_timestamp(t1.D) - unix_timestamp(t0.D) ) < 120)
          AND NOT (t1.E <=> t0.E)
     ) 
     AND t0.E <> 'PR' ;
```

```
 A  | B  | C  | D                   | E 
 :- | :- | :- | :------------------ | :-
 a2 | b2 | c2 | 2017-05-17 01:34:28 | PA
 a4 | b4 | c4 | 2017-05-12 19:16:15 | PA
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=3447d6d7b3effa4a821d953ffa7c8807)*

Don't expect this kind of queries to be efficient in realistic scenarios.

Comment: *"In the current implementations of mySQL, leaving E as a column would work as well"* No, it wouldn't in 5.7 (latest stable version)

Comment: I stand corrected!

Comment: and what about shivam-kumar he ads count on e column and check on this column ?  in your example we are checking on all columns count

Comment: @ceph3us `count(*)` and `count(e)` and `count(a)` and ... are all equivalent when the columns are not nullable.

Comment: second question if i have a column with timestamp and its counterpart can vary by 1 minute  how can I handle this ?

Comment: `count(e)` means: count rows that `e` is not null. `count(*)` means: count rows.

Comment: @ceph3us: it does not make any difference, as far as `E` is not null. I am counting "rows within the group", not how many rows have a not null value in column `E`. If your column `E` could have a NULL value, the `AND t1.E <> t0.E` part should be changed to `AND t1.E is distinct from t0.E` although I'm not sure, by heart, if mySQL supports this part ot the SQL standard, or has some different operator for it...

Comment: but when i have some null data in other rows will result be not affected by count(*)?

Comment: @ceph3us you haven't shown in the example any rows with NULL in column E. So how would we know what you want in those cases?

Comment: If `E` is nullable `count(*)` and `count(E)` are not equivalent. You have to decide which result you would like in that case. If you want  `(va,vb,vc,vd,ve)` and `(va,vb,vc,vd,null)` not to be reported, use `count(*)`. If you want both rows to be reported, use `count(E)`.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - i mean null not in column E in other columns - but good to know if it will be

Comment: @joanolo pleas see ps to question - how handle the data column here

Answer (score 2):

Here is my test table:

[image]

I will give this a try:

```
SELECT A,B,C,D,E,count(E) as dup 
FROM TEST.TESTTABLE 
GROUP BY A,B,C,D
HAVING count(E) = 1;
```

Here is the result I got:

[image]

You can remove the Dup column added for demo purpose and use the below query instead:

```
SELECT A,B,C,D,E
FROM TEST.TESTTABLE 
GROUP BY A,B,C,D
HAVING count(E) = 1;
```